# Expect-like tool for binary protocol testing

Tags: testing, binary, protocols, expect

I'd like to write tests for a simple byte-oriented protocol using something like [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). The test scripts would look like a plain stream of:

```
send "data"
expect "data"
```

(Where send writes to stdout and expect reads just enough from stdin, exiting if it doesn't match.)

I can't use expect itself because it is designed for buffered, line-oriented interactions. Pattern-matching with grep or awk is out for the same reason.

Is there a UNIX tool or library I can use? Even better if it is standard and portable, as it needs to integrate with an existing program.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat ugly solution would be to write a small perl or python script which converts the binary stream to textual hexadecimal numbers and then use Expect to work with that.

Comment: Looks like I'll dissect the protocol with perl's getc(). Not my favourite language to learn, but it *is* ubiquitous.

Comment: pack / unpack would be the best to 'dissect' the protocol, and getc a spectacularly poor choice for a non-line oriented binary protocol.  use read and print (or sysread and syswrite to avoid buffering) to speak to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

[pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) should let you use binary (byte strings) without any problem, if you're OK with Python for the logic -- and it's pure-Python and portable to all sufficiently unix-y platforms (basically one with pty's;-).  Similarly, Python's regular expressions and other byte string manipulations have no problems with any binary string whatsoever; and Python standard library modules like `struct` and `array` ease the manipulation for such binary byte strings and their conversion back and forth to other type of meaningful representations for the data.